# How to double the size of multiple pictures in an array with one Javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an array that contains 5 images. When I mouseover the images I want them to double in size and then return to original size onmouseout. I know how to do this by coding each image individually but I was wondering if there was a way to write one Javascript function (please only Javascript, I'm not allowed to use JQuery for this assignment) that will affect all the images? Here is what I have so far:

My array:

```
var myImages = new Array("usa.png", "canada.png", "jamaica.png", "mexico.png", "pig.png");
```

The function I wrote... I'm not sure about the getElements line...:

```
var doubles = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

      doublesWidth = doubles.width;
      doublesHeight = doubles.height;

    doubles.onmouseover = function() {

       doubles.width = 2 * doublesWidth;
       doubles.height = 2 * doublesHeight;

    }

    doubles.onmouseout = function() {

       doubles.width = doublesWidth;
       doubles.height = doublesHeight;

    }
```

And then in the body I call the images with a height, width and src. For example:

```
<img id="pig"  name="img2" src="pig.png" border="0" height="200" width="350">
```

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle that [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0mtecwj2/) should help you. In the example, it loops over all images and applies event listeners to `mouseover` and `mouseout`, handling the image size accordingly.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
        e.target.width = e.target.width * 2;
    });
    images[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
        e.target.width = e.target.width / 2;
    });
}
```